# Do we need to set HTTP Header when using mpdf?

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf to generate the pdf files using PHP. I am successfully able to output the pdf as inline browser as well as force download using the mpdf options.

My question is do we need to send any HTTP Header information? or mpdf handles that part automatically? I am asking this because some browser may require some kind of header information to make pdf files work properly.

Please note that we are asking about the headers related to PDF file only.

E.g.

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");

header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

header('Content-Length:' . filesize($file));
```

Thanks

Comment: You said you have had success already so what exactly is your question? If it works why do you think  you may need other/more headers?

Comment: I have mentioned that I am asking this because some browser may require some kind of header information to make pdf files work properly. I have seen many examples codes on stackoverflow where users are passing header information however it doesn't required in the mpdf.

Comment: How do you set `Content-Length` for a dynamically generated PDF ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mPDF handles the appropriate headers automatically when using the `DESTINATION::INLINE` or `DESTINATION::DOWNLOAD` options. [You can see the exact headers that are set in the code.](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/development/src/Mpdf.php#L9428-L9460)

Feel free to set additional custom headers if you need to, however it's not needed to correctly view / download the generated PDF document.